# GDAL missing functions [QGIS LTR Linux Ubuntu]

Tags: qgis, gdal, qgis-3, ubuntu, raster-functions

I recently installed QGIS, the 3.10.x A Coruña LTR version following [those instructions](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu). I'm running it on Linux Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver.

GDAL functions (notably in the plugin `Processing`), like `sieve`, `merge`, `polygonize`... couldn't be used as I got this error each time in the Log (here for the `sieve` function):

```
QGIS version: 3.10.4-A Coruña
QGIS code revision: 10bc9f2ff2
Qt version: 5.9.5
GDAL version: 2.2.3
GEOS version: 3.7.1-CAPI-1.11.1 27a5e771
PROJ version: 493
Processing algorithm…
Algorithm 'Sieve' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'EIGHT_CONNECTEDNESS' : False, 'EXTRA' : '', 'INPUT' : '/home/usr/Desktop/folder/qgis/QGIS-Training-Data-2.0/exercise_data/raster_analysis/all_conditions.tif', 'MASK_LAYER' : None, 'NO_MASK' : False, 'OUTPUT' : 'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT', 'THRESHOLD' : 10 }

GDAL command:
gdal_sieve.py -st 10 -4 -of GTiff /home/usr/Desktop/folder/qgis/QGIS-Training-Data-2.0/exercise_data/raster_analysis/all_conditions.tif /tmp/processing_454f018dd02843ff825e6f2494820e75/e60f78775c294aafb296c078daaf2f48/OUTPUT.tif
GDAL command output:
/bin/sh: 1: gdal_sieve.py: not found

Execution completed in 0.08 seconds
Results:
{'OUTPUT': '/tmp/processing_454f018dd02843ff825e6f2494820e75/e60f78775c294aafb296c078daaf2f48/OUTPUT.tif'}

Loading resulting layers
The following layers were not correctly generated.<ul><li>/tmp/processing_454f018dd02843ff825e6f2494820e75/e60f78775c294aafb296c078daaf2f48/OUTPUT.tif</li></ul>You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.
```

So, I focused on the `/bin/sh: 1: gdal_sieve.py: not found` line to try to solve this problem.

1. I can't find any way to retrieve these functions from the QGIS UI;
2. I tried installing the `libgdal` package from the terminal, but it removes essential packages of QGIS. I had to downgrade the GDAL packages in order to reinstall QGIS...;
3. I managed to find the missing python scripts and tried to a) adding a new folder path in the folder scripts option to the folder containing the scripts b) adding directly .py scripts to the already existing folder (path: `/home/usr/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python`).

Both attempts 3. a) and b) made QGIS crash and deactivate the `Processing` plugin when the software was rebooted.

Are those information sufficient to tell what I'm doing wrong and how I could get those functions?

Comment: Did you install gdal-python?

Comment: Through pip3 ? Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had the same problem and installing python-gdal, as suggested by Ian Turton in the comments, helped.
You don't need pip, just use apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get install python-gdal
```

Even if it was installed automatically previously (you can check by running `apt list python-gdal`), reinstalling it manually may help.